# Render curve along any path in CSS?

Tags: css, function, math, rendering

I'm writing a little desktop applet to create and test cubic-bézier functions. Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot of app]

I rendered the actual curve by literally placing A Thousand (1000!) dots of 2x2 px on that view according to the cubic-bézier function. As you can see this "illusion of a curved line" is incredibly jagged. Surely, there must be a better way to do this. And if not, how can I get the points to look less jagged? I did think about putting a blur or shadow on each point, but then I remembered I'm rendering a new set of One Thousand points every time one of the control points changes, and on second thought I didn't want my PC to blow up. Another idea that I had was to kind of rotate the dots orthogonal to the curve's slope at the respectful point, but I'm not sure if that'd work, or how I'd even go about achieving it.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: read about SVG and paths, they are created for such things